# Best technical blog site for existing domain

Tags: domains, blog, code

I would like to have a blog site, tough I have created my own by writing the code.. Huhhh... hosting cost is killing me.

I have my domain name with me and I just wanted to get the blog where I can use my unused domain name.

My blog will me 80% technical [i.e. I will show peices of code and downloadeable content to my user].

Which blog will be useful for me. I just don;t want my URL look like

**http://mysite.hosterName.com**

I want it like this **http://www.mysite.com**

Comment: If you are down voting the question, please be specific with the reason so that I will repeat that again.

Comment: Which blog service are you currently using? Some of them offer support to your own domain free of charges.

Comment: So basically you're looking for free webhosting?

Comment: how much traffic were u getting to kill u in hosting costs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just google for a free web host that supports using your own domain name. Not sure how the hosting cost can be killing you though, most domains are more expensive than the cost of hosting nowadays unless your site is something special. :P

Answer (score 0):

***Originally posted on: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/blog-site-with-existing-domain-name/16210#16210***

You can also make use of whatever blog service as you wish and force the blog to run inside of a frame with the next code in an html file, this way you can use a folder in your main public_html site and make a kind of a redirection to the blogging service as you wish.

The code would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html>
<head> 
  <meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"> 
  <title>Place here your site's name</title> 
</head> 

<frameset title="Player" border="0" frameborder="no" rows="*" onload="doLoad()" onunload="doUnload()"> 
<frame title="Content" noresize="noresize" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://placeheretheblogname.blogspot.com" name="course_frame" scrolling="auto"> 
</frameset> 

</html>
```

The previous code will work just if the blogging service that you are using allows you to run the blog inside of a frame. Of which I have noticed that Blogger (.blogspot.com) and Wordpress will allow you. This trick will work even for static or dynamic pages.

To see the code in action click the next link: http://geppettvs.servehttp.com/blog

When you see inside of the code (with development tools or extensions) you will see the code redirecting to my own hosting service in which I have placed the blog, which is -indeed- other than the link you have clicked.

Good luck!

P.S. This trick will allow you to drop a kind of link that looks like: http://www.yourdomain.com/blog <== change "blog" for whatever you name the blog's folder.